# How to install wireless headset Vengeance 2100

Tags: wireless, sound, usb, games, headset

I have no clue on how to install the headset vengeance 2100, this is the website for reference:

http://www.corsair.com/en/vengeance-2100-dolby-7-1-wireless-gaming-headset

The headset has a usb stick that serves like the interface between the computer and the headset so it can be wireless.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Does the output of `pactl list cards` (you may need to install the package `pulseaudio-utils`) change after you plug in the USB dongle?

Answer (score 1):

I purchased the headset recently, and ran pactl list cards. This is my result for the relevant USB dongle:

```
Card #27

Name: alsa_card.usb-Corsair_Corsair_Gaming_H2100_Headset-00-Headset
Driver: module-alsa-card.c
Owner Module: 49
Properties:
    alsa.card = "2"
    alsa.card_name = "Corsair Gaming H2100 Headset"
    alsa.long_card_name = "Corsair Corsair Gaming H2100 Headset at usb-0000:00:04.0-3, full speed"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:04.0-usb-0:3:1.0"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/sound/card2"
    udev.id = "usb-Corsair_Corsair_Gaming_H2100_Headset-00-Headset"
    device.bus = "usb"
    device.vendor.id = "1b1c"
    device.vendor.name = "Corsair"
    device.product.id = "1b1b"
    device.product.name = "Corsair Gaming H2100 Headset"
    device.serial = "Corsair_Corsair_Gaming_H2100_Headset"
    device.form_factor = "headset"
    device.string = "2"
    device.description = "Corsair Gaming H2100 Headset"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-headset-usb"
    device.intended_roles = "phone"
Profiles:
    input:analog-mono: Analog Mono Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority. 1)
    output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 6000)
    output:analog-stereo+input:analog-mono: Analog Stereo Output + Analog Mono Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority. 6001)
    output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 5500)
    output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-mono: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Mono Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority. 5501)
    off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority. 0)
Active Profile: output:analog-stereo+input:analog-mono
Ports:
    analog-input: Analog Input (priority: 10000, latency offset: 0 usec)
        Part of profile(s): input:analog-mono, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-mono, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-mono
    analog-input-microphone-headset: Headset Microphone (priority: 8700, latency offset: 0 usec)
        Properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        Part of profile(s): input:analog-mono, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-mono, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-mono
    analog-output: Analog Output (priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec)
        Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-mono
    iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec)
        Part of profile(s): output:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-mono
```

This product is not purely plug-and-play. In order to get an audio output, I had to open System Settings > Sound and manually change the output to the Corsair headset. It's a simple fix, but it's something that many could overlook.